# Download artifacts from Bitbucket Download

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I followed this [link](https://bitbucket.org/codedoers/maven-bitbucket-download-wagon/src/develop/) to use Bitbucket as private Maven repository.
I'm able to deploy artifacts to the `Download` section of `REPO_A`, but I can't make `REPO_B` download artifacts of `REPO_A`.

Is that supposed to work? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me without any problem, I copy here my working example.

**Using**:

- maven 3.6.0
- maven-bitbucket-download-wagon version 1.1.0

**Steps** to reproduce it :

- Compile project1 (mvn compile && mvn package)
- Publish project1 (mvn deploy)
- Remove the local project1 package (rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/jg/lib1), so we can check the remote one when compile project2
- Compiles project2 (mvn compile -P customrepos)

  You'll have to specify your profile name that enables your bickbucket repo (check the project2 pom.xml)

[image]

**Files**

project1 pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jg</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>lib1</name>
  <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.codedoers.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>bitbucket-download-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>codedoers</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>bitbucket</id>
                <url>bitbucket://jgoday:mypassword@jgoday/artifacts</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>bitbucket</id>
        <name>bitbucket</name>
        <url>bitbucket://jgoday:mypassword@jgoday/artifacts</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

**Project2** (that consumes lib1)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jg</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>lib2</name>
  <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.codedoers.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>bitbucket-download-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jg</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>customrepos</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>bitbucket</id>
                <url>bitbucket://jgoday:mypassword@jgoday/artifacts</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>bitbucket</id>
        <name>bitbucket</name>
        <url>bitbucket://jgoday:mypassword@jgoday/artifacts</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to not have to use the password? Like the read-only server access tokens they offer for access to the git repo itself? Can they also work here?

Comment: You can use enviroment variables too
<properties>
    <pass>${env.PASS}</pass>
</properties> and then use ${pass} in the repository url

Comment: Or you can put your username and password in ~/.m2/settings.xml under servers > server > your server id

Comment: @Thilo Ok, I understand now. Seems not possible in BitbucketDownloadWagon (if you take look at the sources only establish connection with username and password )